# ng build --prod receives error Module has no static exports true

Tags: angular, azure, build, angular-cli

I receive an error only when trying to build in azure. Local  ng build -- prod works fine.

> Error: Module [path_to_file] has no static exports true

since this is for production I'm not wanting to --aot=false as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256243/ng-build-prod-issue).

> I did run it using --aot=false and am getting the same error.

My build definition is correct as it had worked last week and hasn't been updated.

I'm assuming something has changed in the build that causes this problem.

In my package.json file I am using
"@angular/cli": "^1.2.0" for my devDependency

**Update:**

Upgraded package.json
Build cli devDependency is now "@angular/cli": "^1.3.0"

same error

Comment: I'd highly recommend upgrading to angular-cli 1.3.0. It fixed a lot of the AOT compilation errors, and may fix this for you.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: I believe that the latest standard is `ng build --prod --aot` (without true or false)

Comment: After removing the --aot it built after the upgrade of angular-cli

Answer (score 1):

So it finally built.

Here is what I did

1. [upgraded the package using these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version) using the [npm-check-updates npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

   a. npm i -g npm-check-updates

   b. npm-check-updates -u

   c. npm install
2. Installed all the extra dependencies now required
3. Upgraded to the latest angular
4. ran 'ng build --prod' <-- without the --aot=false